# Problems with background url using SCSS and angular

Tags: angular, iis-7, background-image, postcss-loader

Im using scss in an angular project. 
When i use background image like this:

`url("/assets/images/test.jpg")`
My project builds with no problem and i can see the images on my local or even using `ng serve --build`, but when i upload this to my IIS server, all the background images show a 404 error, because the project is looking for the image in `domain/assets/image/test.jpg` and not in `domain/application/assets/image/test.jpg`.

If i change the image url to `assets/images/test.jpg`using chrome Devtools, it works perfectly.

But when i try to change the code to `assets` without the "/" at the start i get the following error in  the postcss loader:

> Can't resolve 'assets/images/test.jpg' in 'D:\application\src\assets'

Tried with "../" "./" "src/assets" and many others, but the application only compiles when a "/" is written at the start.

Im using basehref to build and rewrite rule on my server but still have the same error.

Comment: try to change the URL in scss file for background-image.

Answer (score 0):

Try building with --deploy-url flag

```
ng build --prod --deploy-url=/application
```

Comment: Found out that is a usual problem with postcss loader and relative paths. 
My building command is this one:
`ng build --prod --base--href /DemoCorebitFront/ --deploy-url=/DemoCorebitFront/`